# Disable "Send by Fax" option in "Add your Attachment dialog box"

Tags: docusignapi

Signer Attachment: How we can disable the "Send by Fax" option in the "Add your Attachment" dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not - there's currently no way to disable the **Send by Fax** button for signer attachments.